# Создание адаптивного кругового заголовка с формами SVG

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Я пытаюсь сделать полукруглый / овальный профиль, который будет адаптивным вместе с содержимым внутри него.

Прямо сейчас он действительно выглядит нормально на рабочем столе, и я действительно не знаю, как заставить его выглядеть корректно на мобильном телефоне или когда окно браузера будет изменено.

Проблема в том, что при уменьшении видимая часть круга становится слишком тонкой в верхней части и почти исчезает, оставляя содержимое заголовка  вне формы.
При увеличении (и на мобильных устройствах / меньших экранах) круг просто становится невероятно огромным, а изображение в svg больше не заполняет форму заголовка.

В идеале заголовок должен выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И на мобильном телефоне вместо того, чтобы выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выглядит более похожее на это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот еще один вопрос, который я получаю, увеличивая масштаб:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Здесь код на fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/150dr2bb/27/)

и вот весь код, необходимый для воспроизведения:

```css
html{
  margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
  background: #161925;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: "moon2reg", "latolight", "calibri", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

header {
  height: 700px;
  max-height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#headerwhitecircle {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 700px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#headercirclecont {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#circleflimage {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 700px;
}

#headercontent {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 700px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items:center;

}

#headerparent {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#headsocials {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

p.svgsocials {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p.svgsocials:after {
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #161925;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: moon2reg calibri;
}

p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.whitetext {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.centertext {
  text-align: center;
}

#titleTxt {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="headercirclecont" style="text-align:center;">
    <svg id="headerwhitecircle" preserverAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#7c3495;stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#f3366a;stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <clipPath id="circleView">
          <circle cx="50vw" cy="-20vh" r="790px"/>            
        </clipPath>
      </defs>

      <circle cx="50vw" cy="-20vh" r="800px" fill="white" /> 
      <circle cx="50vw" cy="-20vh" r="790px" fill="url(#grad1)" /> 
      <image id="circleflimage" width="100vw" opacity="0.1" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Phinizy_swamp_nature_park_floodplain_in_hdr.jpg/1200px-Phinizy_swamp_nature_park_floodplain_in_hdr.jpg" clip-path="url(#circleView)"/>
    </svg>  
  </div>

  <div id="headercontent">
    <div id="headerparent">
      <div>
        <h1 id="logo" class="whitetext">
          Test
        </h1>
      </div> 
      <br>
      <div id="headsocials">
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49831522/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, что у вас могут появляться сложные вещи  в вашем коде, потому что вы пытаетесь контролировать поведение `SVG` с помощью таких модулей, как `vw` и `vh`, вместо использования `SVG viewBox` и использования встроенных функций обеспечения адаптивности SVG.

Когда вы переключаетесь на `viewBox`, все становится намного проще и легче.

Fiddle здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/150dr2bb/58/

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0;overflow:visible}pre{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}a{background-color:transparent}abbr[title]{border-bottom:none;text-decoration:underline;text-decoration:underline dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bolder}code,kbd,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}img{border-style:none}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;line-height:1.15;margin:0}button,input{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button}button::-moz-focus-inner,[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner{border-style:none;padding:0}button:-moz-focusring,[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring{outline:1px dotted ButtonText}fieldset{padding:.35em .75em .625em}legend{box-sizing:border-box;color:inherit;display:table;max-width:100%;padding:0;white-space:normal}progress{vertical-align:baseline}textarea{overflow:auto}[type="checkbox"],[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}details{display:block}summary{display:list-item}template{display:none}[hidden]{display:none}

    html{
      margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body{
      background: #161925;
        height: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        font-family: "moon2reg", "latolight", "calibri", sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    header {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1600px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    #headercirclecont {
      display: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #headerwhitecircle {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 250px;
      max-height: 700px;
    }

    #headercontent {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center; 
    }

    #headerparent {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #logo {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 600px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    #headsocials {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      display: flex;
    }

    p.svgsocials {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    p.svgsocials:after {
      content: ""; 
      position: absolute; 
      top: 0; 
      right: 0; 
      bottom: 0; 
      left: 0;
    }

    h1 {
      color: #161925;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 80px;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-family: moon2reg calibri;
    }

    p {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 30px;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    .whitetext {
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .centertext {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #titleTxt {
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 60px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
      <div id="headercirclecont" style="text-align:center;">
        <svg id="headerwhitecircle" viewBox="0 0 1600 700" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
              <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#7c3495;stop-opacity:1" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#f3366a;stop-opacity:1" />
            </linearGradient>
            <clipPath id="circleView">
              <circle cx="800" cy="-100" r="790px"/>            
            </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <circle cx="800" cy="-100" r="800px" fill="white" /> 
          <circle cx="800" cy="-100" r="790px" fill="url(#grad1)" /> 
          <image id="circleflimage" width="1600" height="700" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" 
                 opacity="0.1" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Phinizy_swamp_nature_park_floodplain_in_hdr.jpg/1200px-Phinizy_swamp_nature_park_floodplain_in_hdr.jpg" clip-path="url(#circleView)"/>
        </svg>  
      </div>

      <div id="headercontent">
        <div id="headerparent">
          <div>
            <h1 id="logo" class="whitetext">
              Test
            </h1>
          </div> 
          <br>
          <div id="headsocials">
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
</header>
```

Источник: [Creating a responsive circular header with SVG shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49839232/7394871) @Paul LeBeau